# reactjs Unexpected token, expected ","

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I create a react app and I was learning to iterate through an array when I got this error.`Unexpected token, expected ","`.I am inspired by react-redux official project:https://codesandbox.io/s/9on71rvnyo  and now I failed and need some help to jump.thanks

```
import { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { StoreContext } from "../index";
import { FaAppleAlt } from "react-icons/fa";
import { AiFillApple } from "react-icons/ai";

export const TodoList = () => {
  const { store } = useContext(StoreContext);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState();
  return (
    <>
      <h1>To Do List</h1>
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={(f) => f}>AddTodo</button>
      <div>
        <ul style={{list-style-type:"none"}}>
          {store.getState().todolist.map((item, i) 
          => { <li key={i}>item.icon+item.title</li>}
           
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
      <button
        onClick={(f) => f}
        style={{
          border: "none",
          backgroundColor: "inherit",
          padding: "14px",
          fontSize: "15px",
          cursor: "pointer",
          display: "inline-block"
        }}
      >
        All
      </button>

      <button
        onClick={(f) => f}
        style={{
          border: "none",
          backgroundColor: "inherit",
          padding: "14px",
          fontSize: "15px",
          cursor: "pointer",
          display: "inline-block"
        }}
      >
        Completed
      </button>

      <button
        onClick={(f) => f}
        style={{
          border: "none",
          backgroundColor: "inherit",
          padding: "14px",
          fontSize: "15px",
          cursor: "pointer",
          display: "inline-block"
        }}
      >
        Incompleted
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

fullproject link:https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-template-forked-ex2ym?file=/src/components/TodoList.js

Comment: i see nothing wrong but i could be missing it. what line does the error happen on? is this the entirety of your code?

Comment: @HolyMoly,I guess you need to be here:https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-template-forked-ex2ym?file=/src/components/TodoList.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issues

It appears you've an extra closing parenthesis and a few other syntactical issues (arrow function not on the same line, etc..). Here are the major issues.

1. In React in `style` object literals the CSS rules are camelCased. It should be:

   ```
   style={{ listStyleType: "none" }}
   ```
2. The `store.getState().todolist.map` doesn't return anything. It should return a list item element. It also probably isn't supposed to render a literal "item.icon+item.title" string, so surround this in curly brackets so you are rendering the mapped `item` values.

   ```
   {store.getState().todolist.map((item, i) => (
     <li key={i}>{item.icon + item.title}</li>
   ))}
   ```
3. `store` is undefined from `const { store } = useContext(StoreContext);`. Provide a valid object to your context that has a `store` key to destructure.

   ```
   <StoreContext.Provider value={{ store: storeFactory() }}>
   ```

This gets your code running and rendering, but I didn't debug any further than that. You've either further issues or you've not fully implemented the ToDo list logic (*Probably the `f => f` callbacks though*).

[image: Edit reactjs-unexpected-token-expected]